# Tkinter - Hide Hint

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, hide, hint

How can this hint be automatically deleted when I select the username and password section? (Don't show after clicking)

```
from tkinter import *
root =Tk()
def save_fonc():
    kul=entry1.get()
    pas=entry2.get()
    print("Username:",kul,"Password:",pas)

#------------------
entry1=Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0,"Username")
entry1.pack()
#------------------
entry2=Entry(root)
entry2.insert(0,"Password")
#entry2.config(show="*")#and also I don't want to show password section.
entry2.pack()
#------------------
buton_kaydet=Button(root,text="Enter",command=save_fonc)
buton_kaydet.pack()

root.geometry("300x200")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is no hint in Your code tho.

Comment: @Matiiss what he means is that 'Username' still stays in the input box after clicked.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez that is definitely not what he wants because it will stay there anyways in the code given, oh I understood

Comment: @Matiiss exactly. He wants to remove it.

Comment: Yes if it's possible I want to remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here You go improved Your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


def save_fonc():
    kul = entry1.get()
    pas = entry2.get()
    print("Username:", kul, "Password:", pas)


def pass_func(event):
    entry2.delete(0, 'end')
    entry2.config(show='*')

# ------------------
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0, "Username")
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: entry1.delete(0, 'end'))
# ------------------
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry2.insert(0, "Password")
entry2.pack()
entry2.bind('<FocusIn>', pass_func)
# ------------------
buton_kaydet = Button(root, text="Enter", command=save_fonc)
buton_kaydet.pack()

root.geometry("300x200")
root.mainloop()
```

So basically `.bind` binds each entry to an event in this case: `'<FocusIn>'` which is triggered when focus switches to that widget. Also in the second case the entry is configured only after event trigger so that 'Password' is visible as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the text when the label is clicked.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def clear_text(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")

entry1=Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0,"Username")
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_text)
```

What this does is bind it to the function, `clear_text`. `clear_text` clears the text from the label.

Complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
root =Tk()
def save_fonc():
    kul=entry1.get()
    pas=entry2.get()
    print("Username:",kul,"Password:",pas)

def clear_text(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")

#------------------
entry1=Entry(root)
entry1.insert(0,"Username")
entry1.pack()
entry1.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_text)
#------------------
entry2=Entry(root)
entry2.insert(0,"Password")
entry2.config(show="*")#and also I don't want to show password section.
entry2.pack()
entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_text)
#------------------
buton_kaydet=Button(root,text="Enter",command=save_fonc)
buton_kaydet.pack()

root.geometry("300x200")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: at the beginning the password will show as `*` You have to config it after event trigger so that that activates when the widget is empty and one starts typing in stuff not from the start

Comment: No problemo @Birkan

Comment: `def clear_text(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")
    entry2.config(show="*")` Yes Matiiss now ist better

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that clears the text in the entry box, and then bind it in the function.

```html
def removeValue(event):
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: I wrote this answer right after @Ismail posted